# Simple networking question

Tags: ethernet

I am new to the site and just passing by to get answers from experts. I am not really into technology but might as well consider you for my question. I would just like to have a basic information on the difference between Ethernet and Internet?

Comment: you might have better results seeking help on [su]. This is a bit outside our domain. The two are not the same in anyway. If you are in a different domain then us the answer might be different though. When I did IT the things we would call ethernet are much different then my understanding as an EE.

Comment: This is also true in the fact the accept answer does not concur with what ethernet is form an EE perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ethernet is a simple exclusive network within an organization while an internet is accessible to all if only one is connected. You can do file and information sharing to your office mates using Ethernet simple set-up. This usually done by most businesses to stay connected with the people within the company. For more details you can have a look at this link. http://www.techyv.com/questions/what-are-intranet-ethernet-and-internet